# Problem with my JavaScript AJAX request in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-8

I have a products range on this site

http://vanquish.websitewelcome.com/~hawko/hawko-lighting/led/
*using jQuery*

In Firefox / Safari, clicking *view* will allow you to see more details on the product on the right. This includes a gallery (if > 1 images), a download *specs sheet* if one is available and view more details.

The JavaScript works like this

- Get preliminary info from list (disable JavaScript to see what I mean)
- Get id from HTML attribute `id`. Uses regex.
- Get JSON from server (extra images, spec sheet filename)
- Show info to user

For some reason, my old friend IE (8 & 7 are my concerns) don't get past the throbber spinning indefinitely. I've tried quite a bit - but I am as a lost as to why. I coded this JavaScript about 6 months ago - so it's not exactly *fresh* in my mind (or probably up to scratch to what I may be writing nowadays).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is complaining because you are setting the [`background-image`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-image) CSS property without the proper `'url("...")'` format (*known as [URI values](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri)*), in your `showGallery` function (*script.js*, line 172) put:

```
$('#product-gallery').css({
  backgroundImage: 'url("' + imagePath + 'thumb-' + images[0] + '")'
});
```

Instead of :

```
$('#product-gallery').css({backgroundImage: imagePath + 'thumb-' + images[0]});
```

Comment: Wow, I would have never thought of that. Thanks a bunch!